# Emitting a list of pointers in signal - how to handle delete

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following memory management question (qt5/c++). I'm making `QListWidgetItems`:

```
QList<QListWidgetItem*> items;

foreach(MyItem myItem in myItems)
{
    QListWidgetItem * item = new QListWidgetItem(myItem.text);
    items.append(item);
}

emit itemsReadyForList(items);
```

When the emitted signal is picked up somewhere, the items can be added to a `QListWidget`, and will be deleted once its destructor or `clear()` is called.

However, how can I prevent the generated list from creating a memory leak when this signal is *not* picked up?

`QListWidget::addItem()` requires a heap object, so I can't make the list of QListWidgetItems stack based and add them with `addItem(*item)`, because once the signal has been processed and the list goes out of scope, the item is deleted.

I thought about using a `QSharedPointer`, but one shouldn't use that when passing the raw pointer to any piece of code that can delete it, which `QListWidget` does.

So am I going to have to make my own pointer class like this (pseudo code):

```
class MyPointer
{
    bool dontDelete = false;
    QListWidgetItem * item;

    QListWidgetItem * getPointerAndYieldControl()
    {
        dontDelete = true;
        return item;
    }

    ~MyPointer
    {
        if (!dontDelete)
            delete item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `QSharedPointer` in the list then when the list is not picked up they will get deleted when the last copy of the list gets destroyed.

When you need to save them you should use the [`clone` of `QListWidgetItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#clone) to create a copy for you to use. Remember that more than one slot can pick up the QList.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make `items` a member of the class which emits the `signal`, and then de-allocate using `delete` in the destructor of this class. It is not a problem to call `delete` on already deleted object if it is `NULL` or `nullptr`. So if the `signal` is not caught in a `slot`, still the items will be deleted. But you have to make sure to assign `NULL` or `nullptr` if the signal is caught in a slot, and the parent `QListWidget` is destroyed.

**EDIT**

As for your comment, I guess your design has to be modified then. Either you will create the items only when needed, and destroy after use, or you should keep them all the time in parent class, use when needed and destroy when parent gets destroyed.

To me a better design would be to keep the strings that will be used as text for the items in a list as member variable. Then in the `signal`, pass these strings. In the `slot`, items will be created and added to the `QListWidget`, and destroy the items with the widget. If you again need them, generate them again.

Comment: But that might delete my list items prematurely. I think in my current scenario it will work though. I guess I'll do that, but I was hoping for an epiphany-answer :)

Comment: @Halfgaar, I guess you can then use `shared_ptr` instead of writing your own.

Comment: I'm writing C++98... But does the `shared_ptr` have such a feature? Why doesn't the `QSharedPointer`?

Comment: I would normally create the QListWidgetItems at that point too, but what I'm actually doing is adding a subclass of QListWidgetItem to the list, and when retrieving the selected item again, ask information about it. And that information comes from where the signal is emitted.